# Combobox Tkinter populating with database values

Tags: python, database, tkinter, combobox, ttk

im trying to populate the combobox with database values and the one ive made for optionmenu works fine. But i cant get it to work with combobox.

```
    # Dictionary with options
    choices = c.execute('SELECT time date FROM data')
    tkvar.set('Select date and time') 

    lablemen= tk.Label(self, text = "Select start time", font=('helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
    lablemen.grid(row = 1 , column = 1)

    popupMenu = tk.OptionMenu(self, tkvar, *choices)
    popupMenu.config(font=('helvetica', 15, 'bold'))

    popupMenu.grid(row = 2 , column = 1)
```

how do i go from optionmenue to combobox?

ive tried this

```
  choices2 = c.execute('SELECT time date FROM data')

    cb = ttk.Combobox(self)
    cb.grid(row = 3, column = 1)

    cb['values'] = choices2
```

and it gave me [combobox result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLCIa.png)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
    cb = ttk.Combobox(self)
    cb.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
    cblist = list()  

    for row in c.execute('SELECT time date FROM data'):

        cblist.append(row)

        cb['values'] = cblist
```